# Libs for work with SSH

Tags: python, ssh, sudo

counsel to the library to work with SSH. The main requirement is normal operation with the utility sudo.
I have already tried and what I am suffering:

- paramiko - can not sudo at all, trying after a call to serve in STDIN password, but sudo wrote that then type: "No ttys present"
- pxssh - mmmmmm, very slow, very very slow, awkward
- fabric - can sudo only in what is an ideal world, as there is to work with different users and where i need send password ?

Have normal libraries that work with sudo, or not?

Comment: Can you reword your question a little bit? `sudo` and `ssh` are two different things. What are you looking for?

Comment: All I just need to connect to the server via SSH and do any task from a privileged account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than force `sudo` to work without a tty, why not get Paramiko to allocate you a TTY?

[Paramiko and Pseudo-tty Allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909481/paramiko-and-pseudo-tty-allocation)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/0.9.3/).

Answer (score 0):

You can configure sudo to work without a real terminal with 'requiretty' setting. From  sudoers manual:

> If set, sudo will only run when the user is logged in to a real tty. This will 
>   disallow things like "rsh somehost sudo ls" since rsh(1)  does not
>   allocate a tty. 
>   Because it is not possible to turn off echo when there is no tty present,
>   some site may wish to set this flag to prevent a user from entering a visible
>   password. This flag is off by default.

This works for me with paramiko. Depending o what are you doing, you can also look at something like [pexpect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect#Description_of_Pexpect).

Comment: Why not allocate a TTY instead?  See the link in my answer.

Comment: @Andrew Aylett: for automation I use SSH with public key authentication only, very restrictive sudoers User_Alias with NOPASSWD (in order to avoid clear text password inside the scripts). Requiring tty allocation in an environment where I will never type passwords is a waste.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with pxssh at first: it was extremely slow!
Here is a way I found to make it run quicker:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pxssh
import getpass

try:
    s = pxssh.pxssh()
    s.PROMPT = "#"
    hostname = raw_input('hostname: ')
    username = raw_input('username: ')
    password = getpass.getpass('password: ')
    s.login(hostname, username, password, auto_prompt_reset=False)
    s.sendline('ls')   # run a command
    s.prompt()             # match the prompt
    print(s.before)        # print everything before the prompt.
    s.sendline('ls -l /tmp')   # run a command
    s.prompt()             # match the prompt
    print(s.before)        # print everything before the prompt.
    s.logout()
except pxssh.ExceptionPxssh as e:
    print("pxssh failed on login.")
    print(e)
```

The key part is `s.PROMPT = "#"` and `auto_prompt_reset=False` in `s.login()`.
This method requires that you know the pattern for the prompt (in my case it is "#", I think the PROMPT attribute can be set to a regular expression).

Answer (score 0):

I also had some problems with login speed on pxssh. I tried using the code referenced above, but still was seeing 10+ seconds just to login. Using the original_prompt argument fixed the issue for me. You need to make sure to set the original_prompt to what you see when you first ssh into the machine, which in my case ended in '>'.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from pexpect import pxssh

host = 'hostname.domain'
user = 'username'
password = 'password'

terminal = pxssh.pxssh()
terminal.login(host, user, original_prompt='[>$]')
```