# Paramiko and sudo

Tags: python, sockets, ssh, sudo, paramiko

I've been searching the nets for some time now for a solution to my problem, and no luck.

My issue is that I can't seem to get sudo commands to run with paramiko.

At first, I tried to simply use the SSHClient().exec_command(command) function to execute a sudo command, but this errors:

```
sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
```

Then, following the advice of this post: [How to make a sudo command using Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934572/how-to-make-a-sudo-command-using-paramiko), I tried this:

```
#self._ssh is the SSHClient object    
self._ssh.invoke_shell().exec_command(command)
```

However, most of the time, this just gives me:

```
File "pipelines/load_instance/ssh_tools.py", line 71, in executeCommand
    stdin, stdout, stderr = self._ssh.invoke_shell().exec_command(command)
  File "<absolute_path>/paramiko/channel.py", line 213, in exec_command
    self._wait_for_event()
  File "<absolute_path>/paramiko/channel.py", line 1084, in _wait_for_event
    raise e
paramiko.SSHException: Channel closed.
```

The other, I'd have to say, 40% of the time, I get this:

```
File "<absolute_path>/paramiko/client.py", line 291, in connect
    sock.connect(addr)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

As a side note, I'm attempting to run these sudo commands on an Amazon Web Services EC2 instance, so I'm confused as to why I would get the Connection Refused error, since each time I run this code it's on a fresh new instance...

Also, I'm using paramiko 1.7.6.

Answer (score 3):

This is a common problem on recent distributions and impacts more than just paramiko.  (I ran into it the other day when I upgraded a box from fedora2 to latest.  Several ssh/sudo management scripts broke)

As long as you have access to the remote host, you can edit `/etc/sudoers` and comment out the line: `Defaults requiretty`

Details in the [sudoers man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers):

> **requiretty**
>
> If set, sudo will only run when the
>   user is logged in to a real tty. This
>   will disallow things like "rsh
>   somehost sudo ls" since rsh(1) does
>   not allocate a tty. Because it is not
>   possible to turn off echo when there
>   is no tty present, some sites may with
>   to set this flag to prevent a user
>   from entering a visible password. This
>   flag is off by default.

Comment: Hello J.J., I have exactly the same problem as kand. If I understand this right, then removing the requiretty flag should solve the problem. However, I still get the same stacktrace as above. What am I doing wrong? (Apologies if this is the wrong place to ask)

Comment: Yeah, same question here. This does not really solve the problem for me, and eventually that line is not even in the /etc/sudoers file by default.

Answer (score 0):

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(cmd,  get_pty=True)
```

Comment: Consider adding a description of your code. It will help future users that visit this post.