# Running Sudo Command with paramiko

Tags: python, sockets, ssh, paramiko

I am trying to execute a `sudo` command on a remote machine using python-paramiko.

I tried this code:

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('192.168.0.104', username='cdc',password='123456')
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("sudo dmesg")
stdin.write("123456\n")
stdin.flush()
print stdout.readlines()
ssh.close()
```

I expected this to bind all three streams and pass the password to `sudo` using the input stream. But it doesn't work and I get this error instead:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/file.py", line 314, in write
    self._write_all(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/file.py", line 439, in _write_all
    count = self._write(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 1263,in _write
    self.channel.sendall(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 796, in sendall
    raise socket.error('Socket is closed')
  error: Socket is closed
```

What is wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: see my answer 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270677/how-to-run-sudo-with-paramiko-python/28011904#28011904

Answer (score 17):

First of all, have you tried in console with `ssh cdc@192.168.0.104 "sudo -S -p '' dmesg"`. If it also fails, then you might check the `sshd` settings and the `sudoer` settings.

If it works well, please add some echo between lines, so that we can know exactly when the exception was thrown. I highly doubt that you should change `sudo dmesg` to `sudo -S -p '' dmesg`.

You might also try my wrapper of paramiko. I can use it smoothly to access any CentOS/SuSE node and perform any commands (w/wo sudo privilege):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from StringIO import StringIO
import paramiko 

class SshClient:
    "A wrapper of paramiko.SSHClient"
    TIMEOUT = 4

    def __init__(self, host, port, username, password, key=None, passphrase=None):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.client = paramiko.SSHClient()
        self.client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        if key is not None:
            key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key(StringIO(key), password=passphrase)
        self.client.connect(host, port, username=username, password=password, pkey=key, timeout=self.TIMEOUT)

    def close(self):
        if self.client is not None:
            self.client.close()
            self.client = None

    def execute(self, command, sudo=False):
        feed_password = False
        if sudo and self.username != "root":
            command = "sudo -S -p '' %s" % command
            feed_password = self.password is not None and len(self.password) > 0
        stdin, stdout, stderr = self.client.exec_command(command)
        if feed_password:
            stdin.write(self.password + "\n")
            stdin.flush()
        return {'out': stdout.readlines(), 
                'err': stderr.readlines(),
                'retval': stdout.channel.recv_exit_status()}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    client = SshClient(host='host', port=22, username='username', password='password') 
    try:
       ret = client.execute('dmesg', sudo=True)
       print "  ".join(ret["out"]), "  E ".join(ret["err"]), ret["retval"]
    finally:
      client.close()
```

Comment: I would like to see an answer to sudo requirement for a shell beyond simply changing your sshd settings.  In other words, assuming I don't have access to the servers sshd settings, how do I run sudo commands?

Comment: @rfportilla My solution does not require changing sshd settings at all. Using my code, you can run any shell command as you do in local.

Comment: "...then you might check the sshd settings and the sudoer settings."  I think the common error here is that sudo can't be run remotely through ssh without a tty: sudo: "sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo." You can get around this by modifying sudoers file, but this is not always an option.  Your solution does not help with this from a client perspective.  I may have down-voted prematurely, but it won't let me take it back now without a change (even a minor change) to the answer.  Sorry.

Comment: @rfportilla Never mind for a down-voting. You have a good point that from a client perspective my solution still requires a tty. In other words, it does not elevate permissions with magic, but fixed a wrong command usage appears in the original question.

Answer (score 11):

Im sorry i dont have time for details answer but i was able to implement sudo commands on paramiko using [this](http://joelinoff.com/blog/?p=905) advise

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import paramiko
l_password = "yourpassword"
l_host = "yourhost"
l_user = "yourusername"
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(l_host, username=l_user, password=l_password)    
transport = ssh.get_transport()
session = transport.open_session()
session.set_combine_stderr(True)
session.get_pty()
#for testing purposes we want to force sudo to always to ask for password. because of that we use "-k" key
session.exec_command("sudo -k dmesg")
stdin = session.makefile('wb', -1)
stdout = session.makefile('rb', -1)
#you have to check if you really need to send password here 
stdin.write(l_password +'\n')
stdin.flush()
for line in stdout.read().splitlines():        
    print 'host: %s: %s' % (l_host, line)
```

Comment: using this method, is there any way to get the return value of the executed command without parsing the output?

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is kind of old but I was wanting to use sudo and paramiko together, too.  It took me a while to figure out this solution.  It may not work for everyone but I figured it was worth adding.

```py
def ssh_handler(hostname, username=USER, password=PASS, command=CMD): 
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(hostname,
                username=username,
                password=password) 
    # set get_pty to True to get a pseudo terminal
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(prepare_command(command), get_pty=True)
    # write and flush the password to the remote terminal
    # note that the password will also be written to the terminal from where the script is executed.
    stdin.write(password+'\n')
    stdin.flush()

    response = stdout.read()   
    ssh.close()
    print(response)
             
     
def prepare_command(command):  
    if (not isinstance(command, basestring)): 
        command = ' ; '.join(command)  
    command = command.replace('"','\"') 
    command = 'sudo -s -- " '+command+' " \n'
    return command


# kind of a dumb example but you get the point 
mycmd = []; 
mycmd.append('cd /dir/this/user/doesnt/have/access/to')
mycmd.append('ls -las')
mycmd.append('cat file_in_dir.txt')

ssh_handler(server, command=mycmd)
```

Comment: What's the point of this line?
`command = command.replace('"','\"')`
Why do you need a backslash in front of double quotes?

Comment: @jxmorris12 - it is escaping the double quote in the string.  I wrote this ~5 years ago so I'm not totally sure but if you look at the following line, `'sudo -s -- " '+command+' " \n'`, you see that the whole command is being passed to sudo between double quotes. Escaping them will allow that to process... straight in the cli, an example would be `sudo -s -- " randomCommand --arg=\"pablo\" "` (probably wouldn't use those padding spaces, but it shows the quotes better here)

Comment: How this solve the problem of providing sudo password?

Comment: How can this work without providing password?

```# stdin.write(password+'\n')  ``` I am confused due to this line.

Comment: Updated the answer to supply the sudo password when running the command.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to implement this solution which was found in other Stackoverflow threads.

https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/60taz7/execute_sudo_su_and_input_password_with_paramiko/df94q7s/

The solution for me was to use `invoke_shell()` when requiring the use of commands with `sudo`.

Answer (score -1):

It worked for me when I combined both suggestions mentioned above:

1. putting "-S -p ''" into sudo command: "sudo -S -p '' dmesg"
2. setting password on stdin:
   stdin.write(password+'\n')
   stdin.flush()

Comment: Please read [answer] and keep in mind that this is **not a discussion forum**.