# How to launch submodules from a python package?

Tags: python, linux, networking, python-3.x, ssh

I am working on a robotics project with my lab. ([Github](https://www.github.com/masasin/kaginawa/tree/client_class)) Most of the main components are done and documented. The setup is as follows:

- We run `opstn` on the base station. It has a server used to communicate controller position to the robot.
- We run `rpi` on a raspberry pi running on the robot. The two communicate via wifi and have a static address. The raspberry pi has a client program which requests the controller positions when it has time, decides what to run the motor.
- The raspberry pi communicates with an mbed via USB to allow for hardware PWM.
- The raspberry pi will also be working with I2C devices for monitoring data, and communicating it back to the base station for processing. This will eventually be run as a separate server process, and the base station will have a client process communicating with it.
- The base station might need to have a client module to interpret the device data, running as a separate process.

The code does work, but we have to run it in a somewhat longwinded way:

- On the base station, `cd` into `kaginawa` and `python -m opstn`, running `opstn/__main__.py`
- SSH into the raspberry pi, `cd` into `kaginawa` and `python -m rpi`, running `rpi/__main__.py`

I was wondering how to properly launch submodules. For the `rpi/__main__.py`, I was thinking of providing two functions (the motor-controlling client and the device server) in `__main__.py`, and use `multiprocessing` to run them. Experiments seem to indicate that this would work.

What I want to do, though, is zip my directory into an executable, and then simply `./start_robot`. This is what the `Makefile` does, and it works well. However, whatever I try, I seem to be unable to start `opstn` at all. And I will also need to work with the SSH too, since I will need to launch `rpi` with `sudo`. I can probably do that with `paramiko` using [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22592827/4322433).

If it is possible, I am thinking of using `os.uname()[1]` to check if it is on the raspberry pi and launch `rpi`, and `opstn` otherwise.

**tl;dr** How do you launch submodules that contain a `__main__.py` from the root `__main__.py` of a python package?

Comment: unrelated: `os.uname()[1]` hack might make things confusing. Less opaque hack is to choose what to run based on the program name (the same runnable zip but different names appropriate for the task). Or better: generate individual scripts (see [setuptools entry-points](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The toplevel directory in the project should not be a Python package. It could be a directory with `setup.py` instead.

You shouldn't `cd` inside Python package. Put your zip somewhere in `PYTHONPATH` (check by `print(sys.path)`) and use absolute names to run submodules e.g., run:

```
$ python -m kaginawa.opstn
```

to run `kaginawa/opstn/__main__.py` script or run:

```
$ python -m kaginawa.rpi
```

to run `kaginawa/rpi/__main__.py`.

If you want to choose what to run at runtime then you could call `kaginawa.opstn.main()` or `kaginawa.rpi.main()` functions in `kaginawa/__main__.py`. And run it:

```
$ python -mkaginawa
```

You could [run the zip directly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5355694/4279).

To simplify including dependencies, you could use PyInstaller, cx_Freeze to bundle your code.

Comment: Thank you! I can't test it for another week or so, but I think calling `opstn.main()` and `rpi.main()` from within `kaginawa.__main__.py` would work, and is exactly what I want to do.