# Doing SFTP operations over sudo in remote machine with Paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, sftp, sudo, paramiko

How do I use Paramiko and `sudo` to run `chmod 775`?

Code snippet:

```
    ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())    
    r_pass = getpass.getpass(prompt='Remote password? ')   
    ssh_client.connect(r_ip, username=r_name, password=r_pass)
    ftp = ssh_client.open_sftp()
    for fn in files:
        print("sending {} of {}".format(count, len(files)))
        ftp.put(fn, posixpath.join(r_path_mark, fn))
        ftp.chmod(r_path_mark+fn, 0o775)
```

The very last `ftp.chmod` command results in a "*permission denied*".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running Sudo Command with paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22587855/running-sudo-command-with-paramiko)

Comment: My guess is that sudo is asking for a password via stdin. If the user your connecting as allows password-less sudo I'd think it'd work. Otherwise, I'm not familiar enough with Paramiko to know if it'd let you send a password on stdin to `sudo` *after* being prompted for it.

Comment: I'd suggest trying Ansible instead

Answer (score 0):

There's no standard way to run SFTP over `sudo` – While not impossible, it involves number of hacks.

For some background my article on using `su`/`sudo` with WinSCP SFTP client:
[How do I change user after login (e.g. su root)?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_su).

---

Alternatively, you can run `chmod` shell command over `sudo`, what is covered in other questions already:

- [Running Sudo Command with paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22587855/850848)
- [How to run sudo with paramiko? (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6270677/850848)

---

Though in general, you should not use `sudo` this way for a command automation.
For alternatives, see:
[Allowing automatic command execution as root on Linux using SSH](https://superuser.com/q/1481318/213663)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone who replied. I did review everyone's feedback. All are good but for our solution, it didnt do it. Thanks also to @cricket_007. My TL suggested I use Ansible as well.

I did get it work. The trick was to call another script wherein the called script resides locally in the remote machine and therefore sudo stuff isn't an issue.

Flow is as follows:

- App server (script 'A' is invoked by user)
- App server (script A does its routine and then using subprocess.call it calls script 'B' also residing in the same App server)
- App server (script 'B' has some magical open source code that I didnt write.. but it invokes a script 'C' residing in a remote server)
- Remote server (script 'C' is able to run everything as sudo su - locally. No special coding needed as its local to the machine << and that was my original problem to begin with)

All good << Just tested the end to end deployment this morning.

Answer (score 0):

Execute command directly in your for loop -

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("sudo su - -c 'chomd 775 $filename'")
```