# How to get root privilege in remote host using python paramiko

Tags: python-2.7, paramiko

I am working on Python paramiko.
As we know in paramiko we can login to a remote host using the credentials

```
ssh.connect(hostname,username=username,password=password)
```

after that if I should get the root privilege by running some command `privileged-mode enable` this will prompt us for a **password**.

Here I am not able to get the **root privileges** to the device and I am facing problem in sending the password.

Can anybody help me!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run sudo with paramiko? (Python)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270677/how-to-run-sudo-with-paramiko-python)

Comment: What problem are you facing in seding the password?